# Haskell の レコード構文(Record Syntax) にて、より簡潔にフィールド(field)にアクセスする方法はありませんでしょうか。

Tags: haskell

以下のようにレコード構文(Record Syntax)にて独自の名前付きフィールド(Named Fields)らを定義し、フィールド(Field)の一部を利用する場合に、より簡潔な方法はありませんでしょうか？

下記のコードでいえば `fNumField Foo{hoge = x} = x ^ 2` の部分が粗雑に感じます。

```haskell
data Foo = Foo{ bar :: String , hoge::Integer} deriving (Show)

main = do
    print $ fNumField a
    where
        fNumField Foo{hoge = x} = x ^ 2
        a = Foo{ bar = "piyo", hoge = 575 }
```

※ (別の質問の方がいいのかもしれませんが) F# や OCamlのような言語と違い「名前付きフィールド」が Haskell には似合わないような気がしています。通常はどうかくものなのでしょうか？

※ 「命名規則や用語がHaskell的に変だ！」という場合もぜひ、コメントや編集などでフィードバックお願いします！

## 追記 :  2015-01-26

回答を参考に修正してみました。

```haskell
data Foo = Foo{ bar :: String , hoge::Integer} deriving (Show)

main = print $ hoge a ^ 2
    where
        a = Foo{ bar = "piyo", hoge = 575 }
```

※ hoge の定義がかぶった場合はコンパイル時に Multiple declarations などと怒られてしまったので、使いどころが難しく感じました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Record syntax を使った時には同名の関数が作られます．また， Record syntax を使ってデータ型を定義してもそうでない記法で値を作ることができます．

そのまま書くならこういう感じでしょうか

```
data Foo = Foo { bar :: String, hoge :: Integer} deriving (Show)
-- hoge :: Foo -> Integer が定義される

main = print $ fNumField a
    where
        fNumField = (^2) . hoge
        a = Foo "piyo" 575
```

Comment: この例では **「`hoge a` でより簡潔に、a のフィールド hoge にアクセスできる」** 、ということですね。
また、値を作るときには「順番が合っていれば field 名が省略できる」わけですか。

なるほど。Record syntax は糖衣構文(Syntax Sugar) のような振る舞いに見えます。